# Conversion of date time in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i'm having some problem converting a sessioned value of datetime to the correct format.

When i use `DateTime lastlogged = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastLogin"]);`i get the value {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} (got the value while debugging)
but the actual value of 
`Session["LastLogin"]` is 2011-08-02 16:35:52.987 which is queried out from SQLServer 2008 data field datetime

Comment: Why do you need to convert the date to a string back and forth using a session variable ? Session variable can hold the date value in a boxed object.

Comment: What are the values of  `Session["LastLogin"]==null` (you want `false`) and `Session["LastLogin"].ToString()` (you want that date)?

Comment: This seems like a string parsing issue. Try using `DataTime.ParseExact(Session["LastLogin"].ToString(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

Your result is `DateTime.MinValue` (midnight on 01/01/0001).

You'll get this result if the value in Session is `null` - this is the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime lastlogged = DateTime.Parse(Session["LastLogin"].ToString());
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. Parse need a string.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot orgot .ToString() method. Changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you storing the value correctly in Session, you can retreieve it through converting it to DateTime.

```
DateTime lastlogged = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastLogin"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others already suggested you can use the DateTime.Parse method. But maybe it would be a better idea to use DateTime.TryParseExact. This way you can define the format of your DateTime

```
DateTime lastLogin;
if (Session["LastLogin"] != null && DateTime.TryParseExact(Session["LastLogin"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out lastLogin))
{
    // TODO: Code that uses the parsed date.
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the Session in ASP.net but isn't it also possible to store whole objects in it? This way it should also be possible to store the DateTime the way it is,  resulting in a code that looks something like this:

```
DateTime result = (DateTime) Session["LastLogin"];
```